# Constraint over the integer division

Tags: prolog, eclipse-clp

I have the following statement in prolog (Eclipse CLP):

```
?-X::1..100,  X/5 #= 2, X = 12.
```

The result is `No.`. I want to check that the integer division of `X` over `5` is equal to `2` or not. If I write the following statement:

```
?-X::1..100,  X//5 #= 2, X = 12.
```

I will get the following error:

> instantiation fault in //(X{1 .. 100}, 5, _703)

So, the question is how can I check the integer division for the variable `X`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using library(ic), which currently does not directly support flooring or truncating divisions.  You can reformulate your condition by introducing a "remainder" variable and using multiplication:

```
?- X::1..100, Rem::0..4, X #= 5*2 + Rem, X = 13.
X = 13
Rem = 3
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```